# HTML/CSS nested divs floating left with scrollbar

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to do a simple effect with a div with a fixed height and width holds a set of divs which can be scrolled left to right.

Here's the code but for some reason the children don't want to float

```
.a       {width:200px; height:200px; overflow-x:scroll; border:3px solid red;}
.a > div​ {width:170px; height:170px; float:left; background:#eee; border:1px dotted #ddd;}

<div class="a">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SZzwP/

Comment: Like this:http://jsfiddle.net/5Rz98/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to (and shouldn't) change your HTML.

Just use `white-space:nowrap` to avoid breaking lines

```
.a{
    width:200px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    border:3px solid red;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.a > div {
    width:170px; height:170px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#eee;
    border:1px dotted #ddd;
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/5Rz98/3/

Answer (score 1):

You have given each child a width of `170px`, but the parent is only `200px`. Please change the width of the child to less than `50px`:

```
.a       {width:200px; height:200px; overflow-x:auto; border:3px solid red;}
.a > div {width:45px; height:170px; float:left; background:#eee; border:1px dotted #ddd;}
```

Also, give `overflow-x: auto` so that initially the horizontal scroll is not shown.

#### In case of a slider, you need to use another markup:

```
<div class="a">
    <div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

#### CSS:

```
.a       {width:200px; height:200px; overflow-x:auto; border:3px solid red;}
.a > div {width:700px; height:170px;}
.a > div > div {width:170px; height:170px; float:left; background:#eee; border:1px dotted #ddd;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fPeUg/

Comment: i need them side by side and the parent div to act as a scroll-able viewer

Comment: Oh! In that case, you need to have another markup. Updating please wait.

Comment: that's the effect but my problem is that I don't know the width in advance. the children is loaded from a database. could be 4, could be 40..

Comment: Then you need to use JavaScript to determine the `width` of the slider, because, that is how sliders work! :)

Comment: Arg! I was hoping there would be an automatic way.

Comment: If you are using PHP or some language, you might hardcode the `width` on the `div` like, `<?php echo ' style="width: ', count($data) * 170, 'px;"'; ?>`. Makes sense?

Comment: @greener See my answer, it doesn't need you to know the width of the slider, and it doesn't require adding a new <div> either...

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want a `div` inside of the container with a width that can accommodate the two `div`'s side by side. Without doing this, you're trying to float 2 `div`'s with a combined width of over `200px` (the container).

---

HTML

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="inner">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.a{
    width:200px; 
    height:200px; 
    overflow-x:scroll; 
    border:3px solid red;
}

.inner{
    width:344px;
}

.inner div{
    width:170px; 
    height:170px; 
    float:left; 
    background:#eee; 
    border:1px dotted #ddd;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/a4T8f/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need another nest div inside .a with a width long enough for all the inner divs to float in, like this:

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    </div>
</div>
​.a       {width:200px; height:200px; overflow-x:scroll; border:3px solid red;}
.b {width:800px}
.b > div {width:170px; height:170px; float:left; background:#eee; border:1px dotted #ddd;}
```

​

Comment: the children divs (1,2,3,4,etc..) are loaded from database so I don't know the width in advance

Comment: @Greener That's going to be a problem, unless you can set set a static width and height that can accommodate them all.

Comment: Could you use an iframe? You could specify the width of the iframe, and the inner page would scroll, regardless what width it was.